# Celerybeat not recognizing new model even though django app does

Tags: django, celery

When starting celerybeat I get the following error:

```
Restarting celery periodic task scheduler
Stopping celerybeat... NOT RUNNING
Starting celerybeat...
Error: One or more models did not validate:
collections.collection: 'language' has a relation with model <class 'languages.models.Language'>, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
collections.translation: 'language' has a relation with model <class 'languages.models.Language'>, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

But the model languages has for sure been added to my django settings, uwsgi and celery starts up fine and everything else but celerybeat work as it should.

It's as if celerybeat works of an old settings file, but that should not be possible or is it? I have recently also moved my settings file.

Comment: What command do you use to start celerybeat ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I had earlier moved my settings files, but not changed this in the celery settings files. So solution was to find the files:

```
celeryd 
celerybeat
in etc/default/
```

and change the path to where the settings files has been moved to.

```
sudo nano celeryd
```

and edit